# CWAC Camera - Implementing switch camera button

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to create a switch camera button with my custom gui. In my `CustomCam extends SherlockFragmentActivity` I have a method called onSwitch() that gets called from the xml android:onClick="onSwitch"

Here is the method:

```
public void onClickSwitchButton(View view) {
        if (current == std) {
            ffc = CustomCamFragment.newInstance(true);
            current = ffc;
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, current).commit();
            isFrontCamera=true;

            return;

        }


        if (current == ffc) {
            std = CustomCamFragment.newInstance(false);
            current = std;
            isFrontCamera=false;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, current).commit();
    }
```

I know that the method triggers because of breakpoints and log statements, but my screen simply goes black, and then comes back as the same std view.

Note: I realize I have to detect if the phone has more than 1 camera, or no cameras at all. But for now, this app is not something I'll be publishing. Just want it for my own personal use.

My CustomCamFragment:

```
public class CustomCamFragment extends CameraFragment {

private static final String KEY_USE_FFC = "com.commonsware.cwac.camera.demo.USE_FFC";

public static CustomCamFragment newInstance(boolean useFFC) {
    CustomCamFragment f = new CustomCamFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC, useFFC);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return (f);
}
```

Comment: "but my screen simply goes black, and then comes back as the same std view" -- I have no idea what you mean by this, sorry.

Comment: It seems like it attempts to make the switch to ffc (temporarily goes black), but it comes right back with a video feed from the std camera.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea what `CustomCamFragment` is. Your code, though, does not seem to actually switch to another camera. You are creating the `CustomCamFragment` via its constructor and not telling it what camera to use. You will notice that is not how [the demo app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/demo) works, where I use a factory method and pass in what camera to use (`DemoCameraFragment.newInstance(false)` for the rear-facing camera, `DemoCameraFragment.newInstance(true)` for the front-facing camera).

Comment: I included my CustomCamFragment code above. It should be identical to yours. I'm not sure why it's not working. Could you take a look? I'm using the Demo-v9 as a example, but still don't understand what could be causing it not to switch.

Comment: @user2676468: One issue, probably unrelated, is that you are making new `CustomCamFragment` instances each time. Only create one per camera, reusing an existing instance if you have it. Beyond that, are you using the value from your arguments `Bundle`? In the demo app, that's in `useFrontFacingCamera()` on the `DemoCameraHost` inner class of `DemoCameraFragment`.

Comment: Hmm... I'm using my own camera host class. `public class CustomCamHost extends SimpleCameraHost` and it's not using the `useFrontFacingCamera()` method. Now how should I pass that class a true or false value?

Comment: @user2676468: Read it out of that arguments `Bundle` (`getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC)`).

Comment: I don't get a bundle in my CustomCamHost class since all it does is extend SimpleCameraHost. I guess maybe I should just ditch my CustomCamHost.java file and try to integrate it into my CustomCamFragment as an inner class?

Comment: @user2676468: Either that, or create a new `CustomCamHost` instance per fragment, passing in the FFC flag to the `CustomCamHost` instance (constructor, setter, whatever).

Comment: Hmm... it seems I need to implement CameraHostProvider in activity. How do I specify that I want to use the one in my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last comment about embedding in fragments: I have disabled the `throw new IllegalArgumentException(...)` from the CameraView constructor in the library and are calling `setHost` myself from my custom `CameraFragment` in `onCreateView`. This way the CameraView's context doesn't have to be a `CameraHostProvider` and you can host the view inside a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I want to switch the front/back camera without pushing a new fragment.  After studying the code of CameraView and CameraHost (SimpleCameraHost), I think the best solution is to just remove the current CameraView instance and add a new one:

```
public class MyCameraFragment extends CameraFragment {

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    addCameraView(view);
}

private void addCameraView(View view) {
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.cameraFrame);
    frame.removeAllViews();
    cameraView = new CameraView(getActivity());
    cameraView.setHost(cameraHost = new MyCameraHost(getActivity()));
    setCameraView(cameraView);
    frame.addView(cameraView);
}

private void doSwitchCamera() {
    // do some change to the settings.
    useFrontFacingCamera = !useFrontFacingCamera;
    if (null != cameraView) {
        cameraView.onPause();
    }
    addCameraView(getView());
 cameraView.onResume();
}

}
```

I hope this may helps someone who want to keep their fragment untouched / simple code.